# Python integration to camera in Google cloud platform

Tags: python, camera

I have written a program in python in Google Cloud platform to detect face from an image.I want to make it reaL time using a camera.But don't know how to connect to the camera from Google cloud platform using python.Please help

Regards, Sharan